# Repository from GitHub in my GitLab project

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I have problem with git repositories.. It's odd problem.

I have cloned project from **GitLab** with SSH.

I have previously set SSH key for my local machine (works for other projects)
I want to push my changes but I get:

> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
> exists.

Odd thing is that I get link from some repository on **GitHub** ??
Thing is I am logged on my GitLab account with my GitHub account.

I tried with `git remote set-url origin https://gitlab.com/project/project-api.git`

When I try: `git remote -v` I get:

```
composer        https://github.com/project/some-github-project.git (fetch)
composer        https://github.com/googleapis/some-github-project.git (push)
```

Also tried:

```
git push -u origin feature/my-first-work
```

and got:

```
ERROR: Permission to https://github.com/project/some-github-project.git denied to ben-user.
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Set the remote url to use ssh instead of https, something like `git remote set-url origin git@github.com:myprofile/my-project.git` or git@gitlab.com...

Comment: Tried. Still getting ERROR: Permission to https://github.com/project/some-github-project.git denied to ben-user. @JoaoVitorino

Answer (score 0):

As long as you see an HTTPS URL right after setting the origin to an SSH URL, you will have this issue.

Check if you are in the right folder, then check which configuration is set with:

```
git config -l --show-origin --show-scope
```

The goal is to check where the HTTPS URL comes from regarding the origin setting.